# How would I get this specific pattern, for loop pattern

Tags: java

I need to be able to get this pattern using for loops:

Q. Write a program to complete the first N rows of the following output. The number of rows N should be read from the keyboard.

**Intended output:**

```
1              
2 4              
3 6 9                  
4 8 12 16
```

**Result:**

```
1              
24              
399               
4161616         
525252525
```

**Attempt:**

(I haven't used scanner yet, because I wanted to try understand how to do it without scanner.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String [] args){

    int odd = 1;
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
      int no=i;
      for(int j=1; j<=i;j++)
      {
        System.out.print(no);
        no = i*i;
      }
      System.out.println();

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You were very close!

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(i * j + " ");        
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

See [demo](https://repl.it/repls/MulticoloredFickleTechnicians)

Comment: To avoid the trailing space: `System.out.print((j == 1 ? "" : " ") + (i * j));`